# web.xml: how to map domain/xx/* to a servlet?

Tags: servlets, web.xml

I have these URLs

```
abc.com/aa/url1
abc.com/ab/url2
abc.com/ac/url3
etc.
```

How to setup web.xml to map this pattern to a servlet?

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>NAME</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>MyClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>NAME</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/xx/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Where xx is a two-letter string. What do I put in the place of xx so that all links above will go to MyClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have more than one url-pattern entries:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>NAME</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NAME</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/aa/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/ab/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/ac/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Unfortunately, the servlet mapping cannot take a regular expression so you can't do a variation of `/a*/*` for the mapping.

Comment: OK Looks like there is no way to do it.